# SVG - Draw scrolling with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll

I am drawing multiple instances of SVGs onto a page (SVGs are in different sections of the page by the way) and have the below code to do this which works but is there any way I can speed up the draw of the paths to make it draw quicker as I scroll? Please help.

```
<svg width="1" height="223" viewBox="0 0 1 223" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path class="path" d="M0.5 -2.18557e-08, L0.50001 223" fill="none" stroke="#F2F3F5" stroke-opacity="0.5"></path></svg>
    
<svg width="1" height="223" viewBox="0 0 1 223" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path class="path" d="M0.5 -2.18557e-08, L0.50001 223" fill="none" stroke="#F2F3F5" stroke-opacity="0.5"></path></svg>



let paths = document.querySelectorAll(".path");

// calculate path length and init
paths.forEach((path) => {
   let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
   path.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `0 ${pathLength}`);
});

// Find scroll percentage on scroll 
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
   drawPaths(paths);
});

function drawPaths(path, pathLength) {
   var scrollpercent =
   (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) /
              (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
              document.documentElement.clientHeight);

   paths.forEach((path) => {
      let pathLength = path.getAttribute("stroke-dasharray").split(" ")[1];
      var dashLength = pathLength * scrollpercent;
      path.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${dashLength} ${pathLength}`);
         }); }
```

I tried adding a transition onto my paths via css but this did nothing. I think the draw seems to only start when the svg is in view not the area where the svg is located. How could I make it start slightly earlier so the whole thing is drawn before I scroll off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the path do not show when you scroll. When calculating the percentage you can add half the clientHeight to the fraction (or whatever it is called -- the number before /) so that the end of the dash is always in the middle (or whatever you need).

I also added the CSS property transition to the path.

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll(".path");

// calculate path length and init
drawPaths(paths);

// Find scroll percentage on scroll 
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  drawPaths(paths);
});

window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
  drawPaths(paths);
});

function drawPaths(path) {
  var scrollpercent =
    (document.body.scrollTop +
     document.documentElement.scrollTop +
     document.documentElement.clientHeight*0.5) /
    (document.documentElement.scrollHeight);

  paths.forEach((path) => {
    let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
    var dashLength = pathLength * scrollpercent;
    path.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${dashLength} ${pathLength}`);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 400vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
}

path {
  transition: all .8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="path" d="M 0.5 0 V 100" fill="none" stroke="orange" />
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="path" d="M 0.5 0 V 100" fill="none" stroke="purple" />
</svg>
```